# Changing MainActivity via PreferencesActivity

Tags: android

I'm trying to change BG of the MainActivity by the PrefernceSetting. 
Preference.xml:

```
...
    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Test_bg"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:summary="Summary test_bg"
            android:key="test_bg" />
...
```

How can I transfer the value into MainActivity? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your activity

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 boolean testBg = prefs.getBoolean("test_bg", false);
 if(testBg){
      //test_bg = true
 } else {
      //test_bg = false
 }
```

to change the value

```
prefs.edit().putBoolean("test_bg", true).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't understand :( ' SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 prefs.getBoolean("test_bg", false); ' - Shall I put in to OnCreate method? And how can I chenge bg? I googled this samplе: RelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor)); I thought that algorythm need to be such as that:

Comment: If ("test_bg" == true) FrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor)); else RelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackColor));