# Changing Drawer Menu via PreferenceActivity

Tags: android

I was asked how to change MainActivity via PreferenceActivity ([Changing MainActivity via PreferencesActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218955/changing-mainactivity-via-preferencesactivity) ) 
Now I'm trying to change DrawerMenu. I have 2 Strings (NAME and EMAIL) in main activity

```
 String NAME = "{name}";
    String EMAIL = "{email}";
```

In OnCreate Method I'm trying to do something like that:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String mName = prefs.getString("test_name", NAME);
        String mEmail = prefs.getString("test_email", EMAIL);
        mName = NAME;
        mEmail = EMAIL;
```

But it doesn't work.

But before I have (in OnCreate method):

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS, NAME, EMAIL, PROFILE);
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String mName = prefs.getString("test_name", NAME);
String mEmail = prefs.getString("test_email", EMAIL);
mName = NAME; //<- Why do you do this?
mEmail = EMAIL; //<- This too
```

You set your `mName` and `mEmail` from your Preferences and after that you change its value again.

You wrote that it won't work with the following:

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS, NAME, EMAIL, PROFILE);
```

Maybe you just wanted to do something like this:

```
NAME = mName;
EMAIL = mEail;
```

Comment: Thanks, I delete there 2 lines. I tried to do like NAME=mName etc. But it says that cannot resolve symbol cuz mName appear just in onCreate method, and even before this method I write String mName and the next line NAME=mName it won't work. And I need mAdapter line (constructor)